# Fixed Buttons/Cells that disappear when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

I'm making my first e-commerce app and am having a little trouble when it comes to the particular views/controllers I should use when setting up the scenes on the main storyboard.

My problem: I'm trying to have three buttons that are locked in place at the top of the view and have them disappear when I scroll through the store items. The store items are currently in a table view controller inside a container in the main view that is below the aforementioned buttons. When scrolling back to the top, the buttons should reappear as they were in the initial scene.

[image: Current Storyboard Layout]

I don't think this current layout is going to work, but I'm kind of lost in how I should design this so I can make it function the way I'd like.

I don't even necessarily want any code, I just want a starting layout to go from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- The layout / functionality is not complex to the degree of isolating

2-  Impelement

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   // check scrollview.contentOffset.y
}
```

3- Make the top 3 buttons inside a vertical `UIStackView` with distribution `fillEqually` and hook it's height constraint as `IBOutlet` and control it's height

```
self.stackVHCon.constant = show ? 300 : 0
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

according to y value of the scrollView's contentOffset